# Get column/row of child within grid of the selected tab instead of only the starting one

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a starting `TabControl` and `TabItem` with a grid inside, and if the grid has above a certain number of children, it generates another `TabItem` with the same grid layout.
Whenever I try to get the column or row of the child in a grid that isn't the starting one with `Grid.GetColumn` or `Grid.GetRow`, it returns the child in the position of the starting grid

Starting `TabControl` & `TabItem` with `Grid`

```xml
<TabControl Name="tabControl" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <Grid Name="gamesGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Function creating a new tab

```cs
private Tab createNewTab(TabControl tc)
{
    var lastTab = tc.Items[^1] as TabItem;
    int header = int16(lastTab.Header.ToString()) + 1;
    Grid grid = new Grid();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (i < 4)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
        else
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
    }

    var t = new Tab(tabControl, header.ToString(), grid);
    tc.Items.Add(t.Item);

    return t;
}
```

`Tab` class

```cs
public Tab(TabControl tabControl, string header, Grid? content = null)
{
    TabControl = tabControl;
    Header = header;
    Content = content;
    Item = new TabItem()
    {
        Header = header,
        Content = content
    };

    //tabControl.Items.Add(Item);
}

public void FocusOnTab(int tabIndex=0)
{
    if (tabIndex != 0)
    {
        this.TabControl.SelectedIndex = tabIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        this.TabControl.SelectedIndex = this.TabControl.Items.Count - 1;
    }

}

public void AddButton(Button button)
{
    Content?.Children.Add(button);
}

public void RemoveButton(Button button)
{
    Content?.Children.Remove(button);
}

public Int16 HeaderAsInt()
{
    return Int16.Parse(Header);
}

public Grid GetContent()
{
    return Content;
}

public bool IsFull()
{
    return GetContent().Children.Count >= Tab.MAX_GAME_COUNT;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Is there a particular code snippet that fails? Which one?